# How to get one iframe from group of iframes in div tags using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get one iframe from group of iframe in div tags.

Here's the code:

```
<div id="mytesting">

<iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://facebook.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://mytalk.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://gmail.com"></iframe>

</div>
```

How to get one iframe from those for suppose I want `<iframe src="http://facebook.com"></iframe>` so how can I get from group of iframes using jQuery?

Comment: `$('#mytesting iframe[src="http://facebook.com"]')`

Comment: You could also add an `id` to each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
var iframe = $('#mytesting iframe[src="http://facebook.com"]');
```

Or

```
var iframe = $('iframe[src="http://facebook.com"]', '#mytesting');
```

Or without jQuery:

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('#mytesting iframe[src="http://facebook.com"]');
```

Comment: thanks for help but i want the functionality to autoclick the iframe src  is it possibe?

Comment: @developert Do you mean redirect to the src address?

Comment: @developert If so try this: `window.location.href = $('iframe[src="http://facebook.com"]', '#mytesting').attr('src');`

Comment: and one thing i am getting  iframe src from dynamic but i will get in <iframe src="http://mytalk.com"></iframe> in this src will change every time so i want to get that iframe src  from group of iframe and redirect to that src

Comment: @developert Actually don't really understand what do you want. You can select element from DOM: `var iframe = $('#mytesting [src="your_src.com"]');`. Than later when you want to redirect to src from this iframe you do: `window.location.href = iframe.attr('src')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var x = $("#mytesting").find("[src='http://facebook.com']")[0];
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bhd7tb6/)